# Problema con función free en lista enlazada

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo un programa con una lista enlazada en C, pero tengo problemas al borrar nodos con el elemento seleccionado. Básicamente, cada nodo tiene tres elementos: el valor, el índice, el puntero al siguiente nodo. Si el valor a ingresar es igual a 0, se debe eliminar el nodo con el índice dado, como da a indicar el programa. Sin embargo, cuando uso la función free en la función borrar nodo (línea 142), ejecuta el programa, pero me da un error (**Process returned -1073740940 (0xC0000374)**). Sinceramente no entiendo por qué, por lo que agradecería que me ayuden. Utilizo Code::Blocks.

Me disculpo por la cantidad de comentarios. Gracias desde ya.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 7
// Bandera
#define INDICE_ENCONTRADO 1
#define INDICE_NO_ENCONTRADO 0

struct nodo {
    int valor;
    int indice;
    struct nodo *sgtNodo;
};

typedef struct nodo *TArray;
typedef struct nodo *Nodo;
// Prototipos.
TArray cargarArray(TArray);
TArray insertarElemento(TArray, int, int);
TArray borrarNodo(TArray, int);
void imprimirArray(TArray);
void liberarMemoria(TArray *);

int main(void){
    TArray lista = NULL;
    lista = cargarArray(lista);
    imprimirArray(lista);
    liberarMemoria(&lista);
    return 0;
}

// Inserta un elemento al "array" según su valor y  su índice.
TArray insertarElemento(TArray lista, int valor, int indice){
    // Primero se recorre el array para ver si existe algún
    // nodo con el índice donde se desea añadir el elemento.
    int bandera = INDICE_NO_ENCONTRADO;
    Nodo tmp = lista;
    while (tmp != NULL){
        // Si el índice de algún nodo coincide con el índice buscado,
        // se levanta la bandera y se sale del bucle.
        if (tmp->indice == indice){
            bandera = INDICE_ENCONTRADO;
            break;
        }
        // Si el índice de algún nodo es mayor que el índice buscado,
        // significa que no se encontró ningún nodo con ese índice y se
        // sale del bucle.
        else if (tmp->indice > indice)
            break;
        tmp = tmp->sgtNodo;
    }
    // Si el valor a insertar es 0 hay otras dos opciones posibles:
    if (valor == 0){
        // Si no se encontró un índice igual, simplemente sale de la función.
        if (bandera == INDICE_NO_ENCONTRADO)
            return lista;
        // Si encontró un índice que coincidía, elimina el nodo, indicando
        // que "fue sobreescrito por 0".
        else
            lista = borrarNodo(lista, indice);
    }
    // Si se encontró un nodo con el índice, simplemente se modifica el valor.
    if (bandera == INDICE_ENCONTRADO)
        tmp->valor = valor;
    // Si no se encontró un nodo con el índice, se procede a crear uno nuevo.
    else {
        Nodo nuevoNodo = malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
        // Verifica que al reservar memoria no haya retornado NULL
        if (nuevoNodo == NULL){
            printf("\nNo hay suficiente espacio en la memoria.");
            exit -1;
        }
        // Se agrega el nuevo valor con su indice
        nuevoNodo->valor = valor;
        nuevoNodo->indice = indice;
        nuevoNodo->sgtNodo = NULL;
        // Si la lista está vacía, guarda la dirección del primer nodo creado.
        if (lista == NULL)
            lista = nuevoNodo;
        // Si el primer elemento de la lista coincide con el primer índice mayor
        // al del elemento que se quiere añadir, el nuevo nodo toma el valor del
        // primer elemento de la lista y el que estaba en tmp pasa a ser el segundo.
        else if (lista == tmp){
            nuevoNodo->sgtNodo = tmp;
            lista = nuevoNodo;
        } else {
            // Si la lista no está vacía, busca el último elemento añadido
            // antes del tmp, que almacena el primer nodo con un índice mayor
            // al del elemento que se quiere añadir.
            Nodo anterior = lista;
            while (anterior->sgtNodo != tmp)
                anterior = anterior->sgtNodo;
            // Al encontrar el nodo buscado, se pone el nodo creado entre
            // esos dos nodos.
            anterior->sgtNodo = nuevoNodo;
            nuevoNodo->sgtNodo = tmp;
        }
    }
    return lista;
}

// Carga el array con los valores del ejemplo.
TArray cargarArray(TArray lista){
    // Esto es lo menos eficiente posible, pero hago para
    // mostrar cómo el array tiene "7 elementos", siendo
    // la mayoría 0.
    lista = insertarElemento(lista,0,1);
    lista = insertarElemento(lista,25,2);
    lista = insertarElemento(lista,0,3);
    lista = insertarElemento(lista,0,4);
    lista = insertarElemento(lista,14,5);
    lista = insertarElemento(lista,0,6);
    lista = insertarElemento(lista,0,7);
    // Sobreescribo los valores con 0, significando que
    // se eliminan esos nodos.
    lista = insertarElemento(lista,0,2);
    lista = insertarElemento(lista,0,5);
    return lista;
}

// Borra el nodo según el índice
TArray borrarNodo(TArray lista, int indice){
    Nodo tmp = lista;
    Nodo anterior = NULL;
    // Si el elemento que quiero borrar coincide con el primero,
    // el segundo elemento pasa a ser el primero.
    if (lista->indice == indice){
        lista = lista->sgtNodo;
    } else {
        // Busco el elemento que quiero borrar.
        while (tmp->indice != indice){
            anterior = tmp;
            tmp = tmp->sgtNodo;
        }
        // Si el nodo a borrar no es el último...
        if (tmp->sgtNodo != NULL)
            anterior->sgtNodo = tmp->sgtNodo;
        // Si el nodo a borrar es el último...
        else
            anterior->sgtNodo = NULL;
    }
    free(tmp); /// LÍNEA QUE SI QUITO NO HAY ERRORES DE COMPILACIÓN
    return lista;
}

void imprimirArray(TArray lista){
    printf("Array:\n");
    TArray tmp = lista;
    int indice = 1;
    while(indice <= N){
        if (tmp != NULL && tmp->indice == indice){
            printf("%d\t",tmp->valor);
            tmp = tmp->sgtNodo;
        } else
            printf("0\t");
        indice++;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
// Libera la memoria reservada para la lista enlazada.
void liberarMemoria(TArray *lista){
    Nodo tmp;
    while (*lista != NULL){
        tmp = *lista;
        *lista = (*lista)->sgtNodo;
        free (tmp);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Trauma muchas gracias! Puse solo las funciones que considero importante, pero no sé si quitar también los comentarios. Están ahí para que se entienda lo que intento hacer, por si acaso. Crees que ya está bien así? Saludos.

Comment: Hola! Por favor ve a [edit] y añade el error que te sale. Tan completo como se pueda

Comment: @Alfabravo Hecho. Ya está bien así?

Answer (score 2):

Hay varios problemas del mismo tipo en la función `borrarNodo` y no son culpa de `free`.

Lo que pasa es que asumes que los punteros tienen direcciones de memoria válidas y obtienes un error al intentar leer o escribir en ella:

```
if (lista->indice == indice){ // Aquí con `lista` 
    lista = lista->sgtNodo; // De nuevo
} else {
    while (tmp->indice != indice){ // Aquí con `tmp`
        anterior = tmp;
        tmp = tmp->sgtNodo; // Otra vez `tmp`
    }
    
    if (tmp->sgtNodo != NULL) // De nuevo con `tmp`
        anterior->sgtNodo = tmp->sgtNodo; // Aquí con `anterior` y `tmp`
    else
        anterior->sgtNodo = NULL; // Aquí con `anterior`
}
```

Arreglandolo quedaría algo así:

```
TArray borrarNodo(TArray lista, int indice){
    if (!lista) // Equivalente a lista == NULL
        return NULL;
    
    // Si el elemento que quiero borrar coincide con el primero,
    // el segundo elemento pasa a ser el primero.
    if (lista->indice == indice){
        lista = lista->sgtNodo;
    } else {
        Nodo tmp = lista;
        Nodo anterior = NULL;
    
        while (tmp && tmp->indice != indice){
            anterior = tmp;
            tmp = tmp->sgtNodo;
        }
        
        if (anterior){
            if (tmp && tmp->sgtNodo != NULL)
                anterior->sgtNodo = tmp->sgtNodo;
            else
                anterior->sgtNodo = NULL;
         }
    }
    free(tmp);
    return lista;
}
```

---

Como sugerencia, en lugar de retornar la lista, podrías pasar un puntero a la variable en la que está guardada y modificarla dentro de la función. Así no necesitas recordar asignarle el valor que devuelve.

Por ejemplo:

```
void borrarNodo(TArray* variable, int indice){
    if (variable == NULL || *variable == NULL)
        return;
    
    TArray lista = *variable;
    // Si el elemento que quiero borrar coincide con el primero,
    // el segundo elemento pasa a ser el primero.
    if (lista->indice == indice){
        lista = lista->sgtNodo;
    } else {
        Nodo tmp = lista;
        Nodo anterior = NULL;
    
        while (tmp && tmp->indice != indice){
            anterior = tmp;
            tmp = tmp->sgtNodo;
        }
        
        if (anterior){
            if (tmp && tmp->sgtNodo != NULL)
                anterior->sgtNodo = tmp->sgtNodo;
            else
                anterior->sgtNodo = NULL;
         }
    }
    free(tmp);
    *variable = lista;
}
```

Y cuando la llamas pasas la dirección de la variable:

```
TArray lista = NULL;
...
borrarNodo(&lista, 4);
```

Comment: Entiendo! Gracias por la sugerencia. Por otro lado, copié el código y me sigue dando el mismo error. Tienes alguna otra idea de qué podría ser?

Comment: Si lo depuraras podrías obtener alguna pista. Hasta dónde llega cuando se produce el error y la pila de llamadas. Si hiciste algún otro cambio en el código también deberías decirnoslo para que podamos ayudarte.